# Assigning XS Cut Line Attributes like River/Reach Name, Stationing, Bank Lines, etc?

Tags: arcmap, flood, hec-ras, hec-georas

I'm working on a flood inundation project as my research study of my course. I am now assigning XS Cut Line Attribute (after constructing the XS Cut Lines) in HEC-Georas > RAS Geometry > XS Cut Lines Attribute > ALL  :: (All Cross-Section Tools). Upon the pop-up of the All Cross-Section Window it appears like the picture below.

[image]

But when I enter "OK" button, an error occurs

[image]

and I enter again, the error looks like this:

[image]

Here is the screenshot of my project.

[image]

Comment: Please provide all error messages as text rather than pictures.

Comment: I am not familiar with hec-georas on arcmap, but I am familiar with [RiverGIS](http://rivergis.com/)  plugin in Qgis and it is quite strict in the order you have to proceed. When I read in your post "I am now assigning" I wonder if you did it right all previous steps. The error does not anything to me, but the last image of your post tells me you have some cross sections that cross each other, that is not correct in the modelling, I am not sure if that triggers and error, but you should correct it.

Comment: Hi Marco - Yes I get it now, the error occurs at the cross sections that cross to each other. Thank YOu so much

Comment: Great, I posted an answer, so it is easier to be found by others once you tag it as *solved*

Answer (score 1):

The last image of your post tells us that you have some cross sections that intersect each other, that is not correct in the modelling, they should not cross each other.

In order to solve it, you are free to draw the cross sections with breakpoints following the assuption behind 1D hydraulic modelling that the cross sections cut perpendicular the flow lines.

The image below shows an example of cross sections with breakpoints.

[image]

The data is based on a modified version of the *Bald Eagle* project data from *HEC-RAS Unsteady Examples* available at the [RiverGIS](http://rivergis.com/) webpage.